# Make a wpf element hide when it loses focous

Tags: c#, wpf, lost-focus

I have a WPF Menu bar which is collapsed when the program starts, and can be shown by pressing F10 (like Firefox)

```
<Menu x:Name="mainMenuBar" Height="20" Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Left" DockPanel.Dock="Top" FocusManager.LostFocus="mainMenuBar_LostFocus">
```

I have code which I though would make it collapse again if it loses focus (i.e. the user clicks somewhere other than the menu bar and the sub menus) using the `FocusManager.LostFocus` property.

```
private void showMenuBar(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.SystemKey == Key.F10)
    {
        mainMenuBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        mainMenuBar.Focus();
    }
}

private void mainMenuBar_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mainMenuBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

When I click away from the menu bar it does not collapse, but it does when I click on the menu bar. This behaviour is the opposite of what I expected, does anyone know why this is happening?

Edit: XAML Code

```
<Menu x:Name="mainMenuBar" Height="20" Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Left" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <MenuItem Header="File">
        <Separator />
        <MenuItem Header="Exit" Click="menuFileExit_Click" ToolTip="Close Program" />
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Options">
        <MenuItem Header="Settings" Click="menuOptionsSettings_Click" />
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Help">
        <MenuItem Header="Read Me" Click="menuHelpReadMe_Click" />
        <MenuItem Header="Version History" Click="menuHelpVersionHistory_Click" />
        <MenuItem Header="About" Click="menuHelpAbout_Click" />
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Try LostKeyboardFocus instead.

Comment: It appears to have the same issue as I described in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to get wished behaviour.
Show menu as you do but even without setting focus.

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.SystemKey == Key.F10)
    {
        mainMenuBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
}
```

Override `OnPreviewMouseDown` for window where your menu is.

```
protected override void OnPreviewMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (mainMenuBar.IsVisible && e.Source != mainMenuBar&& !IsMenuChildMouseDown(e.Source as FrameworkElement))
    {
        mainMenuBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    base.OnPreviewMouseDown(e);
}
```

And create method `IsMenuChildMouseDown(FrameworkElement elem)` for checking if mouse was pressed on child of menu.

```
    private bool IsMenuChildMouseDown(FrameworkElement elem)
    {
        if (elem == null)
            return false;

        DependencyObject parent = elem.Parent;

        if (parent == null)
            return false;
        else
        {
            if (parent == mainMenuBar)
                return true;

            return IsMenuChildMouseDown(parent as FrameworkElement);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are there any changes I need to make to the XAML file to get this to work? What is calling the `MouseButtonEventArgs` in `OnPreviewMouseDown` and what is `OnKeyDown` overriding?
(Or am I completely missing the point?)

Comment: `OnKeyDown` it is only for showing your menu.
`OnPreviewMouseDown` you have to override handler for this event for Window where your menu is. And you don't have to change anything in XAML, except remove `FocusManager.LostFocus="mainMenuBar_LostFocus"`.

Comment: `OnKeyDown` gives this error: Error CS0115 'MainWindow.showMenuBar(KeyEventArgs)': no suitable method found to override

Commenting that out it sort of works, the menu bar doesn't disappear when my mouse goes over it, but clicking on the sub menu buttons collapses the menu and doesn't carry out the button action.

Comment: Can you just comment your `showMenuBar` method and override handler `OnKeyDown` for window where your menu is, like in example.

Comment: Ok, that fixes the error code, but I still can't click sub menu items on the mainMenuBar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97954/discussion-between-mike159-and-melya).